# How to get the id of a window in qml?

Tags: qt, c++11, qml

I want to get the id of a specific qml window in a cpp class, but I don't know how.

something like:

> int id = testWindow.id()

The id that I'm talking about is the id of the window in the system.

How can I do this without change the main.cpp?

Answer (score 2):

The `QQuickWindow` inherits `QWindow` which has the member

```
WId QWindow::winId() const
```

Documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#winId

Comment: How could I this value to a cpp file?, like I want the id of an specific qml window and send this id to a cpp function.

Comment: How can I do this, without change the main.cpp?

Comment: How you are invoking your QML window from CPP code? QQuickView?? or any different way? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html

Comment: I'm using connect to call the cpp function, but to I use the winId to get the id in the system of a specific window I think that is necessary send to my function the object of the window to I use the winId

Comment: In the question, you mentioned "testWindow". What is the type of it?

Comment: its the id of my qml window

Comment: Type I mean, Is "testWindow" an object of QQuickWindow?? or some other..

Comment: I want to get the id of the equivalent of a QLabel component in qml and use this id in a cpp function, but I don't know how.